Can I compare means and demographics (categorical) between my small sample of 45 respondents to a national sample of about 40,000?
I have a sample of 44 participants who answered the same questions as a national sample of about 33,000 participants. I have the full data set of the national sample. I would like to compare means on a few different scales (t-tests and maybe ANOVAs) and compare demographic variables using chi2 or correlation. Will the results of these comparisons be valid or is the difference in the sample sizes too large to trust the results?

FWIW, a t-test will work as intended even when your small sample is $2$ participants and the large one is arbitrarily large, provided the usual distributional assumptions hold.  (There's even a variant with a sample of $1$ participant, but then it's called a "prediction interval" and the assumptions are even harder to verify.)  A differential in sample size is not a problem, because any reasonable (technically: admissible) test will account for both sample sizes.

It is not clear why you would need ANOVA, if you have only two groups to compare (in which case ANOVA is just equivalent to t-test). However, you do need to pay attention to using procedures/software for unequal sample sizes and unequal variances.
In some cases one could neglect variation in the means of the large sample, and use one-sample tests.

Thank you for your help.
